# How to manage different Angular module dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm new to Angular, but as I get more comfortable, I'm writing more modular code, with less logic crammed into the controller, more independent services. However the problem I have is that I end up re-declaring the parent module multiple times, and I run into conflicts when a downstream declaration has different dependancies injected than an earlier one.

Here's a simplified version of what I am currently doing:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

//first instance of "myApp" for some controller
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['dep1', 'dep2']);
var someCtrl = myApp.controller('someCtrl', ['dep3','dep4']);

//later... another instance of "myApp" for another controller
if (!myApp)
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['dep2']);
var anotherCtrl = myApp.controller('anotherCtrl', ['dep3','dep4']);
```

It seems stupid to re-declare `myApp` in this trivial example, but the real project is a large MVC PHP app with lots of re-usable partials etc... so there is no guarantee that the `someCtrl` is always going to be included before `anotherCtrl`. In other words, I need each module to be "self contained", and controllers/services cannot be declared unless attached to the parent `myApp`.

I know that there is **not** a way to dynamically (re)-inject dependancies into a module later: `myApp.addDependancy(['dep7', 'dep8'])`

So the only solution I can think of is to declare `myApp` just once in the `<head>` with every possible dependency of any of the potential controllers/services...

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3' ... ]);
```

...and *never* re-declare it. This would make managing the different dependencies easier, but isn't it basically undermining the purpose of dependency injection? Because I'll be injecting a bunch of unneeded dependencies?

Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work? What is the correct way to approach this? Links to documentation, etc are more than welcome.

NOTE: I've also read that it's a common Angular mistake to over-use the same parent module (`myApp`), but I need the controllers/services to communicate with one another via `$rootScope`, `$watch`, etc... so I think they must all extend `myApp` right?

Comment: initial concept is wrong, you can only declare a module once and yes it needs to include all dependencies. You seem to be confusing controller dependencies with module dependencies

Comment: Sorry. My minimal example was a bit *too* minimal. I declare the second `myApp` conditionally. Updating question now...

Answer (score 0):

How about going with injecting sub-modules into your main like this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1znxmydd/4/)

```
angular.module("main", ['sub'])

angular.module("sub", []).controller("subctrl", function ($scope){
    $scope.hello = "hello I am sub-module";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For small Angular apps, declaring `angular.module` once and including all dependencies is the best way to go.

However, the recommended Angular setup for large scale apps is to create several `modules` and a master `module` that depends on the others.

```
angular.module('xmpl.service', []);
angular.module('xmpl.directive', []);
angular.module('xmpl.filter', []);

angular.module('xmpl', ['xmpl.service', 'xmpl.directive', 'xmpl.filter']);
```

With this setup you achieve your goals of creating feature specific modules and still having the `$rootScope` available to all.

See the official docs on this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#recommended-setup).

I hope this helps.